# C++ refuses to run properly unless cout is used

Tags: c++, sdl

This code compiles, but refuses to make a ball jump when there is no `cout`. When there is a `cout`, it properly makes the object (`dot`) jump. This is just a bit of practice using SDL to create a super primitive game

Main loop:

```
while (!quit){
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        if ((event.type == SDL_QUIT) || ((event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) && (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)))
            quit = true;

    Uint8 * keystates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);

    if (keystates[SDLK_LEFT])
        dot.left();
    if (keystates[SDLK_RIGHT])
        dot.right();
    if (keystates[SDLK_SPACE]){     // press spacebar to jump
        if (!jumping){
            jumping = true;
            jump_time = 0;          // new count - not an actual timer
            SDL_Delay(1);
        }
    }

    while (jumping && ((t.now() + 2) < 1000 / FPS)){  // while jumping and 2ms away from frame cap time
        jump_time += dt;                              // float values. dt = .0002
                                                      // why its so low is beyond me


        // if i dont have this line, the dot will not jump
        std::cout << std::endl;


        // G = 9.81
        // MAX_HEIGT = 20
        // X shift = sqrt(MAX_HEIGHT * 2 / G)
        dot.offset.y = height - dot.offset.h - (-G / 2 * (jump_time - XSHIFT) * (jump_time - XSHIFT) + MAX_HEIGHT);
        if (dot.offset.y > (height - dot.offset.h)){
            jumping = false;
            dot.offset.y = height - dot.offset.h;
        }
    }

    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, 0xFFFFFF);
    dot.blit(screen);

    if (SDL_Flip(screen) == -1)
        return 1;

    if (t.now() < 1000 / FPS){              // cap frame rate
        SDL_Delay(1000 / FPS - t.now());
        t.start();                          // reset timer
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why? I don't understand why this is happening. Does SDL have something to do with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "jumping"?

Comment: this code makes a ball jump on a screen

Comment: Is every line necessary to reproduce the bug? No? Have you posted enough for us to reproduce the bug? No? If you post code that is sufficient and minimal, more people will try to solve the problem.

Comment: this isnt 'every line'. its just some code around the place thats erroring. i dont want to leave out too much code and have someone complain that i didnt place enough code

Comment: Have you tried slowing it down? I'd think that you'd want a small delay each loop so that the dot becomes visible while "jumping".

Comment: now i get it. Benjamin Lindley cleared up your comment. sorry for not getting it sooner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not something specific to using cout.  It only has to do with the amount of time that using cout takes.  That inner loop that the cout statement is in has nothing controlling it's pace.  It just controls the jump for what? 2 milliseconds, right?

During that 2 milliseconds, the dot goes through as many states as it can, then you do another frame, where it get's another 2 milliseconds.  That process is repeated until the dot completes it's jump.

When the cout statement is in there, it probably takes up a significant portion of that 2 milliseconds, meaning that it takes the dot more frames to finish it's jump.

When the cout statement is taken out, the loop just goes so fast, that the jump is completed in very few frames, possibly just one.  So either it's so fast that you just don't see it, or it's so fast that you *can't* see it, because it's done before the screen ever updates.

I'd recommend you work out a mechanism for timing the jump consistently.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing its more the std::endl part that matters.  Implicitly, endl forces a flush of the stream, which ensures data is printed.  See if SDL has something to flush the screen.

Comment: +1 @calccrypto Instead of bitching about C++ try reading library documentation in detail! Buffered write to stdout has nothing to do with the C++ language. To confirm it is an issue with the write buffer not being flushed you should try replacing `std::cout << std::endl;` with `std::cout << "\n"; std::cout.flush();` Then try removing the call to flush and see if your problem comes back.

Comment: the `std::cout.flush()` isnt needed to allow the code to work. just `std::cout << "";` worked too.